# What's the meaning of "at employer's election"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

What's the meaning of "at employer's election" in the phrase:

> Side artist shall perform as a vocalist on the master embodying the performance of main artist for inclusion, **at employer's election**, on a record to be released for sale to the public.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site.  Recording contracts are notorious for having "gotcha" clauses that can cause the artist to not get paid, to not get exposure, and/or to not be able to get out of the contract.  This question should be asked of a lawyer who is familiar with such contracts.

Comment: Thank you, Jasper. I've been reading about those "gotcha" clauses a lot. I'm a amateur composer and musician. I'm trying to get some of my songs on line but I'm worried about my rights so I started reading some contracts available on the internet to try to learn something. I'm still learning English so it gets even more difficult. Thank you again even if you can't help with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an odd and legalese way of saying "choice". The employer may choose to include the vocals of the side artist on a record. But the employer is not compelled to do this. Wiktionary lists this meaning as "archaic", but it may have lingered in legal documents.

However I'm not a lawyer, and if you have any concerns on the meaning of a contract you should be hiring a representative.

Comment: Hi, James, thank you a lot for your help and advice, it makes sense now and I can understand it. Probably some day I'll hire a specialized lawyer but at the stage I am in music production it still doesn't justify the big expense so for now I'm just trying to build my own "How not to be a complete idiot in recording contracts" at the same time I try to improve my English. Thank you again. All the best.